# Changing html with Regex in C#

Tags: c#, html, regex, parsing

I've got source string like

```
<p>blablabla</p>
<p><img style="float: left;" src="../Content/attachments/455dd178-db28-4856-85e8-c65c8e6b04df_312540909.jpg" alt="455dd178-db28-4856-85e8-c65c8e6b04df_312540909.jpg" />blablabla</p>
<p><img style="float: right;" src="../Content/attachments/dec0f850-2921-4bf7-87b8-d2410e04a841_image001.gif" alt="dec0f850-2921-4bf7-87b8-d2410e04a841_image001.gif" width="100" /></p>
```

For each img element I need to remove alt attribute, and replace src elements with srcFileName.Substring(37).

Can't figure out the regex needed. Please help.

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/

Comment: OK, I got it. So Html Agility Pack to the rescue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to use Html Agility Pack for this